# How to create separate alert for each time series in a group-by query in Prometheus alert-manager?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager, grafana-alerts

I am using Prometheus alertmanager to set alerts on some of the metrics. One of the metrics is using `group by` query and then the alert is set on that generic query.

Example: The metric on Grafana dashboard to calculate the time since last successful training of the model:

```
time() - max_over_time(max(spark_job_success_time{model=~"mymodel.*"})  by (model) [24h:1m])
```

This query creates a separate time series for each `model` with name matching with `mymodel.*`.

I want to set an alert (using Prometheus alertmanager) on this metric which would be triggered whenever a particular model (say `model='mymodel.abc'`) crosses the threshold set by the alert.

Right now, the expression is like this:

```
max(<the_above_query>) > 100
```

But this triggers only once whenever one `model` crosses the threshold, and this alert is not triggered for subsequent `models` that also cross the threshold (i.e. is triggered at most once regardless of multiple models crossing the threshold set in the alert).

I want to create an alert for each `model` and would like to have the alert triggered as many time as the number of models crossed the threshold. How to do this using templates in alertmanager?

Comment: You mentioned it only triggers once but if you go to ```<prometheus_url>/alerts``` do you see the alerts? If so it might be worth checking out the inhibition rules in the alertmanager config:

https://prometheus.io/docs/alerting/latest/configuration/#inhibit_rule